# jQuery: Not firing event after click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

**In action:** http://3.alphenweer.nl/weer/
**Code:**

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.categorie[data-cat]').click(function(){
            $('#cat-'+ $(this).attr('data-cat')).slideToggle('slow');
        });
    });
```

```
<span class="categorie" data-cat="nieuws">Nieuws</span>
<div class="box" id="box-nieuws">
    <a href="/pages/nieuws/nieuws/alphen.php">Alphen</a>
    <a href="/pages/nieuws/nieuws/nederland.php">Nederland</a>
</div>
```

**Problem:** When i click on a menu button (In the example: click on 'Neerslag' or 'Satteliet') nothing happens. I think the selector isn't correct, but it should be. Can you guys help me?

Comment: What's `#cat`? Can't see it in the code you posted.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$('#box-'+ $(this).attr('data-cat')).slideToggle('slow');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Already found the problem:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.categorie[data-cat]').click(function(){
        $('#cat-'+ $(this).attr('data-cat')).slideToggle('slow');
    });
});
```

In the third line, `$('#cat-'` ... should've been `$('#box-'`

Answer (score 1):

I think you're a bit confused. It appears that you want to use the data attribute of the clicked `.categorie` to slideToggle the corresponding element. So, you can do:

```
$('.categorie[data-cat]').click(function(){
    $('div[id=box-"' + $(this).attr('data-cat') + '"]').slideToggle('slow');
});
```

or, assuming a structure consistent with the one you have posted, it can be simpler:

```
$('.categorie[data-cat]').click(function(){
    $(this).next(".box").slideToggle('slow');
});
```